# How to automate in SQL query split using Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, loops, dataframe

Here's my query

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT id, timestamp, location_id FROM orders', con=db_connection)
```

I want to split to this

```
df1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT id, timestamp, location_id FROM orders where id<=1000000', con=db_connection)
...
df100 = pd.read_sql('SELECT id, timestamp, location_id FROM orders where id>99000000 and id<=100000000', con=db_connection )
```

I don't want to hardcode because it's prone to mistakes, how suppose to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of [`chunksize` parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
sql_reader = pd.read_sql('SELECT id, timestamp, location_id FROM orders', 
                         con=db_connection, chunksize=1000000)

dfs = [df for df in sql_reader]
```

`dfs` - is a list of DataFrame's, so:

- `dfs[0]` - first DF (first 1000000 rows)
- `dfs[1]` - second DF (next 1000000 rows)
- and so on ...

if you need a full table - `pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)` will return you one DataFrame, which contains **all** rows from the `orders` table

NOTE: you might get `MemoryError` exception if it doesn't fit in memory

Comment: so if I want to call one chunk, I just call `df1`, `df2`, etc

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir, no you access DF's in `dfs` like a regular Python list - `dfs[0]` - first DF, `dfs[1]` - second DF, ..., etc.

Comment: so if I call `dfs` it is a full table?